# How to create parameterized and reusable gulp tasks

Tags: node.js, gulp

Is there a way to make this generic to the point where I can have one copy of it and pass the config item, and file list into it rather than duplicating it for every file/config combination?

I'd love to have something like

```
gulp.task('foo_test', function (cb) {
   run_tests(files.foo_list, config.fooCoverage);
   cb();
}
```

Note on potential oddities in the code
 I'm using [lazypipe](https://github.com/OverZealous/lazypipe) and [gulp-load-plugins](https://github.com/jackfranklin/gulp-load-plugins) full file [here](https://github.com/skarfacegc/FlowTrack2/blob/master/gulpfile.js)

```
// test the server functions and collect coverage data
gulp.task('api_test', function (cb) {
    gulp.src(files.api_files)
      .pipe(istanbulPre())
      .on('end', function () {
          gulp.src(files.api_test_files)
            .pipe(mochaTask())
            .pipe(istanbulAPI())
            .on('end', cb);
      });
});

var istanbulAPI = lazypipe()
  .pipe(plugins.istanbul.writeReports, config.apiCoverage);

config =  {
   apiCoverage: {
        reporters: ['json'],
        reportOpts: {
            json: {
                dir: 'coverage',
                file: 'coverage-api.json'
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gulp is just JavaScript.

You can write plain old regular functions, just as you normally would:

```
function run_tests(srcFiles, srcTestFiles, coverageConfig, cb) {
  var istanbul = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plugins.istanbul.writeReports, coverageConfig);

  gulp.src(srcFiles)
    .pipe(istanbulPre())
    .on('end', function () {
       gulp.src(srcTestFiles)
         .pipe(mochaTask())
         .pipe(istanbul())
         .on('end', cb);
     });
}

gulp.task('unit_test', function (cb) {
   run_tests(files.lib_files, files.unit_test_files, config.unitCoverage, cb);
});

gulp.task('api_test', function (cb) {
   run_tests(files.api_files, files.api_test_files, config.apiCoverage, cb);
});
```

Note that the callback `cb` is just another parameter that is passed to the `run_tests` function. If it was called immediately after calling `run_tests` that would signal task completion to gulp before the asynchronous code in `run_tests` has actually finished.

Comment: Thanks.  I used grunt for long enough that I think I forget that gulp really is plain old js.  The amount of duplication in my gulpfile was bugging me.  Thanks for taking the time to expand answer based on actual src.

Comment: Now it's time for Gulp 4. I provided a new answer below to address this issue.

Comment: @Jos where is your answer below? I would be interested if there was a change in gulp 4

Comment: @Merc: I have deleted it since it was not a proper answer. I ended up doing it completely different from what I had posted. I will put a new answer below for you.

Comment: @Merc: voila. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Lazypipe was a solution (and there are other alternatives) but since Gulp 4 these do not seem to work anymore. Gulp 4 does not pass the stream to pipe functions. Yet the gulp.src(...) function returns a stream.

Also a nice feature of gulp 4 is that functions with Promises can also be a task.

So in the end I came up with this solution that worked for me. With my `gulpfile.js` looking something like this:

```
const {
  src,
  dest,
  series,
  parallel
} = require('gulp');

// other gulp packages omitted in this example...

const myReusableJsParser = (sources, destination) => {

  return src(sources)
    .pipe(stripComments({...}))
    .pipe(obfuscator({compact:true}))
    .pipe(...) //etc
    .pipe(dest(destination));

};

const parseScriptsX = () => {
  return myReusableJsParser('./js/x/**/*.js', './dist/js/x/');
}

const parseScriptsY = () => {
  return myReusableJsParser('./js/y/**/*.js', './dist/js/y/');
}

// more
...

const cleanUp = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  try {

    deleteFiles('./dist/').then(resolve).catch(reject);

  } catch(err) {
    reject(err);
  }

});

// export
module.exports = {
  default: series(cleanUp, paralell(parseScriptsX, parseScriptsY), paralell(...)),
  ...,
  clean: cleanUp
};
```

Comment: Cool thanks. I ended up doing something similar where I used the power of Promises in gulp tasks. But it's nice to have an example with params that you can pass on to the function. Thank you